# Error occurred during initialization of VM: Could not reserve enough space for code cache when executing jar file as regular user on Centos 7

Tags: java, jar, centos

I have a Centos 7 machine with 64gb memory (49gb available) where I am experiencing an issue when trying to execute a jar file as a regular user with the following command:

`java -jar jarfile.jar`

It returns the error:

`Error occurred during initialization of VM`
`Could not reserve enough space for code cache`

However, when I switch to the root user and execute the same command, it runs successfully. I have checked that the user executing the jar file is the owner and the permissions of the file are set to:

`-rw-rw-r--`

I have also checked that there is enough space available on the machine.

Can anyone kindly suggest what could be causing this issue and how I can resolve it to enable the jar file to be executed successfully as a regular user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated /etc/profile with the below to resolve

```
     LIMITUSER=$USER
        if [ -e "/usr/bin/whoami" ]; then
                LIMITUSER=`/usr/bin/whoami`
        fi
        if [ "$LIMITUSER" == "root" ]; then
                ulimit -n 6144 -u 14335 -m unlimited -d unlimited -s 8192 -c 1000000 -v unlimited 2>/dev/null
        elif  [ "$LIMITUSER" == "uptime" ]; then
                 ulimit -n 1024 -u 2047 -m unlimited -d unlimited -s 8192 -c 1000000 -v unlimited 2>/dev/null
        else
                ulimit -n 6144 -u 14335 -m unlimited -d unlimited -s 8192 -c 1000000 -v unlimited 2>/dev/null
        fi
```